# Python - Unable to create an awaitable class (awaitable instance gets created instead)

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

Python doc's suggest that one can implement `__await__` method that returns and iterator and the class will become awaitable. I tested the following code.

```
class AwaitableClass:
    async def set_attr(self):
        self.result = await some_coro()
    def __await__(self):
        return self.set_attr().__await__()

async def main():
    obj = await AwaitableClass() #obj gets bound to None
    obj = AwaitableClass() #Creates an instance of AwaitbleClass
    await obj #Calls __await__
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If I understand your question, you are trying to create a class that is also an iterator. I have added an answer to that effect, but let me know if I am misunderstanding so I can update my answer.

Comment: It is not clear what your question is. What do you want your code to do that it isn't doing currently? As far as I see you've implemented __await__ in a way that makes sense, it returns an iterable and you can successfully await it.

Answer (score 0):

You can [create async iterators/generators without classes](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0525/#asynchronous-generators), for example:

```py
async def things():
    for i in range(10):
        yield i
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def run():
    async for thing in things:
        print(thing)
```

Likewise, to [do this in a class](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#asynchronous-iterators), you need to implement `__aiter__` function and `__anext__` *coro* functions. Like:

```py
class TestImplementation:
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 0

    def __aiter__(self):
        return self

    async def __anext__(self):
        self.count += 1
        if self.count > 10:
            raise StopAsyncIteration
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        return self.count

async def run():
    async for thing in TestImplementation():
        print(thing)
```